Blend words (Portmanteaus) in Torah
I came across a "portmanteau" in Midrash Tanchuma, Ki Tisa 5:

בַּכּוֹשָׁרוֹת (from Tehillim 68:7)

Which is a combination of בָּכֵי
and שִׁירָה, as Hashem's matching of people, against their will, can have some people who end up crying because they do not like their match, and some people who end up singing with joy.
Are there any other portmanteaus (pshat or drash) in Torah (excluding names)?

Including names?

התרשתא ,טטפת,  כומז , אלדד מידד  צלמות come to mind, if you include names

See edit everyone

There are many. שוע טווי ונוז comes to mind.

אין זקן אלא זה שקנה חכמה

What do you mean by "excluding names"? Only excluding the names of people and places, or also the names of things like טוטפות?

-1 You confuse "which is" and "is interpreted as". Midrash merely offers a creative rendition of a rare word.

@AlBerko That's debatable and irrelevant.

@shmosel What? The whole question is predicated on creative allegory, this is not a blend-word, and nobody, as I've checked, translates it that way. Where exactly do you see in the word כושרות the words בכי and שירה?

If you are looking for examples that appear to be portmanteaus even on a p'shat level, one example seems to be "משתחויתם" in Y'chezkeil 8:16 (see Rashi, and even more explicitly Radak, cf. Y'rushalmi Sukka 5:5).
